# Passing extra params through text_field_tag in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in trouble with a form I'm doing on rails 3.

What I want to do is:

I want to pass an extra parameter only to decide how many builds you want to do 
to the next form. I'm trying to pass the value through a text_field_tag, but I can't get it 
on the controller side.

This is what I've done:

Model:

```
  class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :resume,
                 :title,
                 :prelude,
                 :chapter_numbers

    attr_accessor :chapter_numbers
    # etc etc etc

  end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@story) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.input :prelude, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, style: 'width: 100%' } %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= text_field_tag :chapter_numbers %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

the extra parameter is :chapter_numbers, which I want to catch in the controller as 
params[:chapter_numbers], but it's not working. Tried to add it as virtual attribute (don't know if it's necessary)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you paste the params you are receiving in controller through logs . i believe it should be there one more thing if you want to access that in model than you need to add it as a virtual attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text_field_tag` is an independent field, and won't be sent in your params

---

**`text_field_tag` And `text_field` Are Different**

You'd need to use `f.text_field` because this will send the required params to your controller, like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :chapter_numbers %>
```

or in your case (with `simple form`):

```
<%= f.input :chapter_numbers, as: :text  %>
```

[Good resource here about this](https://railsforum.com/topic/936-difference-between-text-field-tag-and-text-field/)

Comment: tried with f.input, but it didn't work. I'm using pry to check the params, and it doesn't return :chapter_numbers, when I try params[:story][:chapter_numbers] it returns NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Forgot that detail! In fact, the params[:chapter_numbers] is getting to the controller, but I redirect to another action. How can I pass that value to other controllers? Thanks

Comment: lol so you're redirecting to another action? Can you explain this? The problem you'll have here is that params are only passed from the `view` to the `controller, and aren't available unless you set them in some persistent object, like a `session variable`. If you can let me know more about what you're trying to achieve, we'll be able to help more

Comment: I did it, what I'm actually doing is calling a create action, and then redirecting to edit action, where I build some nested forms based on that value. what I did was to pass the params when redirecting. redirect_to edit_story_path(id: @story, chapter_numbers: params[:story][:chapter_numbers]). I don't know if I shouldn't be doing like that

Comment: You can do it for sure! Congrats on getting it sorted :) I would mention that you'll have all your params in your URL (highly inefficient), and you'll have to rely on the correct params being passed for your form to work